# Unmatched second part of surrogate pair (0xdf2d)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jackson

When I'm searching Elasticsearch via its Java cleint, I'm seeing the following exception very rarely:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched second part of surrogate pair (0xdf2d)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator._throwIllegalSurrogate(SmileGenerator.java:1842)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator._shortUTF8Encode2(SmileGenerator.java:1663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator._shortUTF8Encode(SmileGenerator.java:1629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator.writeString(SmileGenerator.java:855)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.writeString(JsonXContentGenerator.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.writeValue(XContentBuilder.java:1240)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.writeValue(XContentBuilder.java:1274)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:810)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.TermsQueryBuilder.doXContent(TermsQueryBuilder.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder.toXContent(QueryBuilder.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.QuerySourceBuilder.innerToXContent(QuerySourceBuilder.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.innerToXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:681)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.toXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:659)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ToXContentToBytes.buildAsBytes(ToXContentToBytes.java:63)
    ... 81 more
```

I can't reproduce it with the same request.

I just can see Jackson Smile involved by looking at the stack trace but I have no idea what the problem is.

Anyone seeing the exception?

Comment: In Jackson your variable name must match your json entry, you want to match. Please, add your json mapping and variable names.

Comment: @AbdullaAlSun As I said, the problem can't be reproduced with the same request. So matching names is not a problem here.

Comment: It looks like whatever String you are passing in has broken characters in it. This is a helpful read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode

Comment: @IanGabes Sorry, if my question was not obvious but I already see the Unicode problem judged by Jackson Smile. My question is why the problem occurs in Elasticsearch Java client occasionally.